# What's the meaning of "thus far only" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is the writer saying that the US hasn't banned **chloramphenicol?**

> Many countries have not banned the usage of these harmful drugs in apiculture. The EU has banned all three while the US has **thus far only** banned chloramphenicol.

Comment: You have to consider "thus far" separate from "only" when understanding the meaning.

Comment: Parse it as [thus far] [only], not [thus] [far only].

Comment: To add to choster's comment, **[thus far](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/thus-far)** means "until now or until the present stage in a process".

Answer (score 1):

*Thus far* is the same as *so far*.

So in your sentence: *Only chloramphenicol* has been banned *so far* meaning that for now, at the moment of speaking, there are no other drugs yet, out of those three, that have been banned by the US.

Answer (score 0):

it means - out of many harmful drugs, US has, so far, banned only chloramphenicol.

Comment: They don't mean 'out of many harmful drugs'. They are referring to the three that the EU has banned already. In the US only one of those three has been banned, which is chloramphenicol.

Comment: You are right. It's just 3.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "thus far" means "currently" or "as of right now", with the presumed expectation that this can, will, or might change in the future.  The only purpose for that phrase is to make the insinuation that things can, will, or might change.

This reads just fine, and would be considered reporting a fact:

```
The EU has banned all three while the US has only banned chloramphenicol.
```

in comparision:

```
The EU has banned all three while the US has thus far only banned chloramphenicol.
```

is going beyond just reporting a fact and injecting a probably non-fact.  Without clarifying why the phrase was added, the purpose is likely to try and convince readers that the US is slow to follow suit but may (or should) do so,  or is possibly already in the process of expanding the ban to include more than just the one chemical mentioned.  Without a follow up of more facts stating the US currently considering changing, it forms (or tries to form) an opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The author states that the US has banned chloramphenicol, but the syntax leaves a lot to the imagination.  As written, the sentence tells us that so far the US has banned chloramphenicol, but has taken no other action (fine the manufacturers, modify the drug, who knows?)

The word **only** is probably misplaced and the clause should read **the US has thus far banned only chloramphenicol** which means that the US has not yet banned the other two drugs.

In general the word **only** should be placed as near as possible to the word it modifies, in this case chloramphenicol.